# Why does the SIFT algorithm also capture keypoints at points where there is no change in color components?

Tags: image-processing, sift

###### Why asking image processing in here?

My question is, about image processing. I can't find stackexchange site to ask about image processing, so I asking in here. Image processing is closed at computer vision, in Deeplearning.

###### Question

I see the SIFT algorithm, and I have some questions. The question is, "If given images are simple colored images, then SIFT algorithm can catch the keypoints?"

So, I make simple images like below with `mspaint.exe`
[image]

I Think SIFT algorithm catch keypoints near edges or outsides of rectangle. But the results are quite different.

[image]

Please see the red rectangle at the very bottom of the image. As we can see, SIFT algorithm catch the center of the rectangle.

I think center of the rectangle has not any light changes, so I don't know why this points are keypoints.

###### Running code

```
import cv2 as cv

img=cv.imread('test.png') # read image
gray=cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

sift=cv.SIFT_create() 
kp,des=sift.detectAndCompute(gray,None)

gray=cv.drawKeypoints(gray,kp,None,flags=cv.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
cv.imshow('sift', gray)

#print(kp)
print(len(kp))
k=cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```